# How do I create an observable from the onmessage callback?

Tags: javascript, websocket, rxjs

I am fairly used to RX having used it in .NET and Java, I am expecting to be able to do the following:

```
Rx.Observable.fromCallback(websocket.onmessage)
    .map(...)
    .subscribe(...);
```

however, the console has the following:

`Uncaught TypeError: Rx.Observable.fromCallback(websocket.onmessage).map is not a function`

which would appear to indicate that the `fromCallback` is not returning an Observable.

What am I doing wrong here? Have I misunderstood what `fromCallback` is doing and I need to use a `Subject`? Can I not wrap some arbitrary handler in an observable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are actually looking for [`fromEvent`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromevent.md) or [`fromEventPattern`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromeventpattern.md):

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(websocket, 'message').map(/*...*/).subscribe();

Rx.Observable.fromEventPattern(
  function add(h) { websocket.addEventListener(h); }, 
  function remove(h) { websocket.removeEventListener(h); })
 .map(/*...*/)
 .subscribe();
```

The first one will attempt to use some of the standard ways of subscribing to an event emitter, which WebSocket is. However, if that fails you can use `fromEventPattern` instead to specify how handlers are added or removed from your object.

One additional note, JavaScript does not pass along an implicit reference to the instance of the object you are using as C# and Java do, so your code `fromCallback(websocket.onmessage)` is not passing along `websocket`, it is passing along the reference to the method from the function prototype. `this` will be determined at execution time.

`Rx.Observable.fromCallback` is for functions whose last argument is a callback function which is a standard pattern for asynchronous JavaScript code. Further, the `fromCallback` method does not return an `Observable` it returns a function that when called returns an `Observable` i.e.

```
function methodWithCallback(arg0, arg1, cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    cb(arg0 + arg1);
  }, 2000);
}

var newMethod = Rx.Observable.fromCallback(methodWithCallback);

//[After 2 seconds] 3
newMethod(1, 2).subscribe(console.log.bind(console));
```